# I have tried all solutions I have found yet I can't find a solution - Pylance(missingImports) for vs code

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, importerror, pylance

I am a beginner, and its been hard to know where to search info about the problem, but I have been all day searching solutions yet I haven't found anything that would help

words I am trying to import:

```
words = ["aback","abaft","abandoned","abashed"... etc]
```

my file In which I am trying to import:

```
from words import words
import random
import string
```

the error popping:
[image]

I am trying to import my file words to the dictionary sorter but pylance does not recognize the words file.

I have found some tutorials that seem to be useful for me but are only for MacOS and I am in Windows

if some one can comment a possible solution that would help me a lot

Comment: Please post code and errors as plain text.  Images are hard to work with, for lots of good reasons.

Comment: is it well done now?

Comment: `words = ["aback","abaft","abandoned","abashed"... etc]` Is this in a file called `words.py`?  And if so, where is that file located in your directory structure?

Comment: words is not in a file called words.py

Comment: there is a main folder where I have all my code, then the folder of this proyect where I have both files

Comment: Ok, so it's not in a file named `words.py`.   What is the filename?

Comment: just the name words

Comment: Python code files must have a `.py` file extension.

Comment: dam... thaks, didn't knew that
so sorry for making a dumb question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from words import words
```

The first words should be a folder or module or python file.

You can create a new python file named **words.py**. And in this file:

```
words = ["aback","abaft","abandoned","abashed"... etc]
```

Then you can use `from words import words` to get this array.

By the way, please do not use spaces in file naming. You can use **dictionaryRandomSorter** or **dictionary_random_sorter** instead of `dictionary random sorter`.